# ImportError with endpoint tutorial

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm having issues with GAE tutorials. To start even most basic on working, I had to reinstall pyyaml.

Now I am getting:

```
INFO     2014-12-26 15:06:11,200 module.py:718] default: "POST /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs HTTP/1.1" 500 -
INFO     2014-12-26 15:06:11,203 module.py:718] default: "GET /_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis HTTP/1.1" 500 60
ERROR    2014-12-26 20:06:11,236 wsgi.py:263]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py",
line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py",
line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py",
line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
ImportError: No module named helloworld_api
```

I followed [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/backend/write_api) to the dot, multiple times. Same error every time.
Current itiration of me trying to solve this, looks like this:

**app.yaml**

```
application: *my id here*
version: 1
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1

handlers:
# Endpoints handler
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: helloworld_api.APPLICATION

libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: endpoints
  version: 1.0
```

.py is fairly long, but its a copy paste from Step 7 [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/backend/write_api)

Doesn't matter how I launch it, command line or App Engine Launcher, same error occurs. It seems bizarre since it clearly launches from the Launcher fine, it recognizes it. No error on start of the server. When I tried basic tutorial, it worked also fine, something with endpoints is just not clicking for me.

I get a blank screen at API explorer.

File structure is:

```
-project
 -django
   -helloworld
    app.yaml
    helloworld_api.py
    helloworld.py
```

I call the command from django directory with `dev_appserver.py helloworld` from Google Cloud SDK Shell

Comment: mind posting your helloword_api.py?

Comment: updated it with the .py part

Comment: hmmm I wanted to doublecheck if there was a problem with the actual py by comparing it to that :p I assume you did it more than once. the "APPLICATION = endpoints.api_server([HelloWorldApi])" is a step that could cause such an error if you skip it. Sure it's in there? because if not, it all points to your folder structure being possibly broken?... lemme check if I can get the same error

Comment: Updated with file structure, and it has that line. Copy pasted it identically, few times by now

Comment: Have you tried adding `__init__.py`?

Comment: in api file? yes, but it simple doesnt see it right now, as per error code

Answer (score 1):

If you could add the contents of `helloworld_api.py` to your question, I could look through it and see if that's the issue, because sometimes, with Python, you have to be exact about the structure of the document, or it won't be recognized as a document. I've had issues with this before.

Comment: Its a copy paste from step 7 from the tutorial I linked. It is fairly long piece hence I didnt put it in. Still want me to include it?

Comment: I'm not sure anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I just copied the contents of app.yaml and helloworld_api.py from that tutorial page and it works perfectly. I would suggest you check that the contents of the files match the tutorial page.

Also, I see you have a helloworld.py file in your directory. I don't see this file in the tutorial. What does it contain?

Comment: Thats the point, it works for everyone but me, I want to figure why is that. helloworld.py is from basic tutorial at GAE and it works fine, stand alone

Comment: I got the point. I was trying to point out that the problem is clearly not with the tutorial code. That leaves only the possibility that the reason for it not working is on your system. So we cannot help you based on the current information you gave us. If you post your actual files we can try using them to see if we can reproduce.

Comment: How do you want me to share the files? I listed the code and structure

Comment: That's your choice. The files aren't large, so you could paste them here. Or upload somewhere like [pythonfiddle.com](http://pythonfiddle.com) and post the link here.

Comment: It is in the link that is provided, no need for fiddle. Also error is not in that file, it is not even reaching that file as you can see from the error. It seems like SDK/Environment issue?

Comment: If you are referring to the link to the tutorial, then I can't try to help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, but I was able to resolve it. I think you need to make sure that the file name of the .py file is the same in app.yaml.

In my case, I had created the app in main.py. So make sure in app.yaml it is listed as main.application. It needs to be "main" and not helloworld_api.APPLICATION. Also make sure the case for "application" matches.